# Spine.js Dynamic Models // Coffeescript Dynamic Class Creation

Tags: inheritance, coffeescript, spine.js

Ladies & Gentlemen,

Short Version:
Trying to dynamically create a Spine Model Class. Basically I get a JSON from the server telling me what the model name is and what it´s attributes are and then I´ll try to create a class derived from spine.model.

As Spine.js uses a Coffeescript class that is configured before being instantiated I wanted to create one dynamically - Which works, only some of the inherited functionality does not.

Problem:
While inherited functions work, fetch doesn´t seem to work and there seems no way to set the class name.

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/eqksA/5/

It´s fascinating how far you can push Coffeescript. Thanks in advance for any clue to solving this advanced riddle.

Comment: I´ve updated the Code: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/eqksA/6/ I´ve made a stupid mistake of calling the Instance instead of a Class method. Thanks Sandro!.

Comment: This is the latest code: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/eqksA/

Comment: I´ve tracked the strange behavior down to a problem with binding events in spine on Models inherited from other Models : http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/MfZTb/

Comment: There's some weird side effects on this for me. For some reason, the first AJAX call outputs to the first div, the second call outputs to the first and second div, and the third AJAX call outputs to all three divs. I think this has to do with the @configure call in the class definition, but I might be wrong.

Comment: It works when re-configuring the newly created classes. This causes all events to be thrown way (unbind). It then needs to be re-configured and newly extended. A bit strange but it works.

Comment: The code with re-configuring: http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/MfZTb/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how Spine.js works, but looking through your code I noticed `fetch` is a class method of `CDModel`, and that's how you use it in the first test where you fetch 'static message,' but for the dynamic class you're trying to use `fetch` as an instance method.

I changed the name to DynamicClass for my own clarity, but I did the following:

```
// The class name is DynamicClass
DynamicClass = gen ("Testclass")
// ... more code ...
DynamicClass.bind("refresh change", (item) -> $("#element2").html DynamicClass.first().message )

params = type: 'POST', data: 'json=[{"message":"Dynamic msg"},{"message":"another message"}]'
DynamicClass.fetch(params)
```

I noticed this only works when you comment out the call to the first test though, but not being familiar with Spine.js I'm not entirely sure why this occurs.

I hope this helps.
Sandro

Comment: Hi Sandro, Thanks so much for looking into it. You´re absolutely right. The real code calls the Class Method and still fails. The updated code doesn´t work either... I can´t seem to get the fetch method to actually fetch the json... http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/eqksA/7/

Comment: Hmm... I´ve tested some more, and I´m getting the dynamic model to load. But it´s like the more I test, the stranger the behavior gets. Latest is at http://jsfiddle.net/thomasf1/eqksA/10/

Comment: I fooled around with your code a little and update the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/eqksA/15/
Had to mess around with how the class was created and also have to call configure and extend on the model after the dynamic class was generated. It seems to work though.

Comment: Thanks so mutch... This works perfectly. It then works because configure unbinds all events. Which is also the reason for it needing to be re-configured...

Comment: How is it expected to behave? When I try that fiddle, all I get is "loading" and nothing really happens...